# ADO.NET entity data model generate from database and skip columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4.1

I want to generate EDM from my database file (.mdf), but i don't want to work with all columns. How can i skip these columns from .edmx?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the properties after Entity generates the model? I don't think there is a way to tell it to ignore *before* generating the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't select specific columns at the time of generation.  But, if you only want to work with a subset of columns, let the EDM generate the entire table; then in the designer surface you can select the columns you don't need and hit delete to remove them from the model.

One note is that if your database has certain constraints, such as non-nullable columns with no default value, an exception will be thrown if you try to add or update entities without those columns in your model.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this manually.

Obviously you can map tables as show here, but then you have to go through and manually remove columns. At least this is what I have been told.

[image]

Comment: no, i select 1 table and inside the table i want to skip or remove collumns... i try to make a screenshot

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am saying. You can't do it. You have to manually remove them. "ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN column_name"

Comment: sorry, im totaly amateur in this, where need to write this command?